# Como armazenar valores de uma lista em variáveis individuais sem saber seu tamanho?

Tags: python, lista, variáveis

Preciso atribuir cada valor inteiro dentro uma lista de no mínimo 1 item e no máximo 10 itens à uma variável separada. Depois diminuir 1 de cada item, somá-los e imprimir o resultado. Esses valores númericos serão obtidos por um `input`. Por exemplo:

```py
#Se ela tiver 2 itens:

lista = input().split()

#convertendo para tipo inteiro:

def int_converter(list_x):
    counter = 0
    while 1 == 1:
        list_x[counter] = int(list_x[counter])
        if counter == (len(list_x) - 1):
            return list_x
        else:
            counter += 1
            continue

int_converter(lista)

#armazenando em variáveis:

a1, a2 = lista[0], lista[1]

#fazendo as operações que preciso e imprimindo o resultado:

resultado = (a1 - 1) + (a2 - 1)
print(resultado)
```

O problema é que não sei quantos números serão digitados pelo usuário, só que serão  no mínimo 1 e no áximo 10. Como faço isso sem criar uma condição para cada caso? Fiz isso e o código ficou gigante.

Se há um jeito de fazer isso já com as listas, por favor me informem como.

Comment: Por que precisa fazer isso? Se não sabe quantos valores serão digitados, como saberá quais são as variáveis que existirão? Não pode utilizar a própria lista?

Comment: Não porque vou ter que fazer operações com os elementos dessa lista. Preciso diminuir 1 de cada elemento da lista e somar o resultado para depois imprimir na tela. Continuando o exemplo de 2 itens:
resultado : (a1 - 1) + (a2 - 2)

print(resultado)

Comment: Mas você consegue fazer isso com a lista...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss como?

Comment: Será mais fácil você colocar na pergunta exatamente o que precisa fazer. O que você perguntou está parecendo ser um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vou editar agora

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você obterá a lista com:

```py
lista = input().split()
```

Mas devemos lembrar que os valores serão *strings*. Para subtrair 1 de cada valor e depois computar a soma, basta utilizarmos da função `sum` e do *generator comprehension*:

```py
resultado = sum(int(numero) - 1 for numero in lista)
```

Se a entrada for `2 3 4`, o resultado será 6, referente a soma `(2-1)+(3-1)+(4-1)`.

Comment: Tentei e deu certo, obrigado. Entendi o que fez mas tenho uma dúvida:
o que é  _generator comprehension_ ?

Comment: @GustavoMatias Quando você cria um gerador a partir do `for` *inline*.

Comment: Entendi. Tem como mostrar como ficaria o laço `for` sem ser inline? Achei exemplos na internet mas não to conseguindo replicar nessa situação

Answer (score 1):

Não há sentido em armazenar cada valor da lista em variaveis diferentes, lembrando que uma lista é um vetor de variaveis e tem como um dos objetivos justamente não ter de declarar N variaveis na mão, não há outra maneira de fazer isso senão na mão mesmo.
O sentido mesmo é acessar os valores da lista através dos indices

```
lista = input().split()

#convertendo para tipo inteiro:

def int_converter(list_x):
    for i in range(len(list_x):
        list_x[i] = int(list_x[i])


int_converter(lista)

#Acessa todos os valores da lista e entrega de parametro para print

for i in range(len(lista)):
    print(lista[i])

#Ou...

for i in lista:
    print(i)
```

edit: Já que comentou a razão do porque quer fazer isso, continua sendo inválido tentar atribuir cada elemento pra uma variavel de tipo primitivo. Tente visualizar a razão da existencia de vetores, no caso do seu problema, algo assim resolveria:

```
def somaEstranha(lista):
     x = 0
     for i in range(len(lista)):
        x += lista[i] - i

     # Caso a primeira subtração tenha de ser por 1, 
     # basta fazer "x += lista[i] - (i + 1)"

    return x
```

Lembre-se, toda vez que uma ação em um código tiver se tornado repetitiva, é sinal de que ela tem que ser substituida por apenas uma vez a instrução dentro de um loop, vetores servem para esse caso de repetição de atribuição, também

Comment: Tentei sua solução e não deu certo. Pra você entender melhor o que eu queria fazer aqui está o meu código completo e funcionando: https://code.sololearn.com/cM11QSh7P3SS/#py
link do desafio que estava tentando resolver (a explicação):  (https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p2/2007/f1/choc/)